# How to access keystore from pallet?

Tags: pallet, validator, key, authorship

I want to add keys from a pallet in the keystore so that these keys can participate in the consensus[validation/block authorisation].

Is it possible to perform? If yes how?

Comment: Can you provide more information? I'm not sure what you mean "I want to add keys from a pallet in the keystore".

Comment: @liamaharon it means that he want to add account keys which can participate in the consensus, like we do from terminal[cli command] to add keys into the keystore and these keys/accounts can participate in the network for consensus. same thing can we perform from the pallet?